# Azure Information Protection | How to decrypt .EMLs coming from EWS API?

Tags: azure, exchangewebservices, microsoft-information-protection

Given:

1. We use EWS API to download email messages from Office 365 (Exchange Online)
2. When emails are encrypted using AIP, body comes in encrypted
3. Admin user is super-user - this user's creds are used to make requests against EWS

Ask:

1. In order to decrypt, it seems that we need to use `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-handler-protection-cpp`. Is this the correct API to use? 
   [image]
2. If so, above API is in C++. Is there anything available in C#?
3. Simple samples of how to decrypt a message would be appreciated?
4. Final question, is there a way to avoid decryption all together by setting some higher-level permission on the user that we use for EWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shipped support this week for decryption of MSG files. We don't yet support protected EML files. You may be able to convert the EML to MSG, then use the functionality we [announced here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Information-Protection/Microsoft-Information-Protection-SDK-1-2/ba-p/447638) to decrypt.

The [File API package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.InformationProtection.File/) is available via NuGet. This package includes both .NET and native libraries.

[All of our samples are available here](https://aka.ms/mipsdksamples). I haven't published a decryption example, yet, but you need to call FileHandler.RemoveProtection() followed by FileHandler.CommitAsync() and that'll give you the decrypted output.

Comment: Tom, thank you - would be great to publish full sample. I will try it and once I prove that this works, I will mark this as an answer. Side question - can we use Basic Authentication for this or we have to use Auth 2.0 - we use Basic for EWS

Comment: Tom, are EML files supported now?

Comment: We did some investigation last quarter and found that supporting EML files will be a considerable amount of work and lands outside the charter of our SDK. We did build an **inspect** feature that will obtain the components of a message.rpmsg file. The pattern to implement is similar to:
 
Use some existing 3rd party package (Aspose is one) to parse the contents of the EML file.
* Extract the message.rpmsg and pass to our inspect function, getting all of the attachments and plaintext email body.  
* Attachments would then need to be passed in to the MIP SDK File APIs to decrypt.

Comment: You can try this out by using the --inspect and --enable_msg switch in the sample apps and passing in a message.rpmsg file.

Comment: @tom_moser - thank you for explaining this path for EML vs. MSF. On a bit separate note: Is there a better way to get data "uprotected" from EWS without using SDK at all? For example, I can see there there is a "super user" concept that allows to get data "unprotected" from Office365. Can we use the exact role or something like that to get data from office365 "unprotected"? In other words, can Office365 do the "decryption" so we can avoid using SDK all together?

Comment: we also cannot find “inspect” function anywhere? Can you please point us to it and a sample on how to use it?