# Decrypting an encrypted office 365 email from MS 365 Personal account using MIP SDK

Tags: c#, azure, office365, exchangewebservices, microsoft-information-protection

I have followed the link [Decrypting an encrypted office 365 email using MIP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127217/decrypting-an-encrypted-office-365-email-using-mip-sdk)  using MIP SDK(1.6.113) to decrypt an rpmsg successfully when the users and application are in the same Azure AD environment.  If I try to decrypt an rpmsg that was sent from an MS 365 Personal account, I am not able to decrypt.

The AcquireToken code gets called twice. The first call to acquire token, when calling AddEngineAsync, has the incoming parms:

identity = Microsoft.InformationProtection.Identity
authority = "https://login.windows.net/common"
resource = "https://syncservice.o365syncservice.com/"
claim = ""

The second call to acquire token, when calling CreateFileHandlerAsync, has the incoming parms:

identity = Microsoft.InformationProtection.Identity
authority = "https://login.windows.net/54485d23-c432-40fe-8436-6091d627118c"
resource = "https://aadrm.com"
claim = ""

Then the code gives me the following exception:

```
System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=One or more errors occurred.
Source=mscorlib

StackTrace:
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action.CreateFileHandler(FileOptions options) in C:\MyGitHub\MipSdk-Dotnet-File-ServicePrincipalAuth-master\mip-sdk-dotnet-file-SPA\Action.cs:line 179
at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action.RemoveProtection(FileOptions options) in C:\MyGitHub\MipSdk-Dotnet-File-ServicePrincipalAuth-master\mip-sdk-dotnet-file-SPA\Action.cs:line 212
at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\MyGitHub\MipSdk-Dotnet-File-ServicePrincipalAuth-master\mip-sdk-dotnet-file-SPA\Program.cs:line 111

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action.CreateFileHandler.AnonymousMethod__0() in Action.cs

Inner Exception 1:
AccessDeniedException: The service didn't accept the auth token. Challenge:['Bearer resource="https://aadrm.com", realm="54485d23-c432-40fe-8436-6091d627118c", authorization="https://login.windows.net/54485d23-c432-40fe-8436-6091d627118c/oauth2/authorize"'], CorrelationId=f63bb5f6-009f-4b9f-a4b7-621df958845b, CorrelationId.Description=FileEngine
```

What could be the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like the problem is your auth token, sending an invalid one or expired, from your error log > The service didn't accept the auth token.

Comment: I am acquiring the token in the code so it is fresh.  What is interesting is that if I use the ADAL with this, the second acquire token brings up a signon to authorize against a Contoso Demo.  So, I assume that https://login.windows.net/54485d23-c432-40fe-8436-6091d627118c/oauth2/authorize is a Contoso Demo application.   How could this happen?

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting the token with MSAL

- when AcquireToken is called with resource **"https://syncservice.o365syncservice.com/"**
  you must call app.AcquireTokenSilent(new[]{ **"https://psor.o365syncservice.com/UnifiedPolicy.User.Read"** }, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
- when AcquireToken is called with resource **"https://aadrm.com"**
  you must call app.AcquireTokenSilent(new[]{ **"https://aadrm.com/user_impersonation"** }, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();