# Exception decrypting .msg files using MIP SDK: NoPolicyException: Label policy did not contain data

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/quick-email-msg-csharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127217/decrypting-an-encrypted-office-365-email-using-mip-sdk) to decrypt .msg using the MIP SDK. Following is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private const string clientId = "[test client id here]";
    private const string appName = "MIPSDKTestApp";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Provide path to protected msg file:");
        string inputFilePath = Console.ReadLine();
        string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFilePath), "Unprotected_" + Path.GetFileName(inputFilePath));

        // Initialize Wrapper for File API operations.
        MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File);

        // Create ApplicationInfo, setting the clientID from Azure AD App Registration as the ApplicationId.
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = new ApplicationInfo()
        {
            ApplicationId = clientId,
            ApplicationName = appName,
            ApplicationVersion = "1.0.0"
        };

        // Instantiate the AuthDelegateImpl object, passing in AppInfo.
        AuthDelegateImplementation authDelegate = new AuthDelegateImplementation(appInfo);

        MipContext mipContext = MIP.CreateMipContext(appInfo,
                                 "mip_data",
                                 LogLevel.Trace,
                                 null,
                                 null);

        // Initialize and instantiate the File Profile.
        // Create the FileProfileSettings object.
        // Initialize file profile settings to create/use local state.
        var profileSettings = new FileProfileSettings(mipContext,
                                 CacheStorageType.OnDiskEncrypted,
                                 new ConsentDelegateImplementation());

        // Load the Profile async and wait for the result.
        var fileProfile = Task.Run(async () => await MIP.LoadFileProfileAsync(profileSettings)).Result;

        // Create a FileEngineSettings object, then use that to add an engine to the profile.
        var customSettings = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        customSettings.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("enable_msg_file_type", "true"));

        // Create a FileEngineSettings object, then use that to add an engine to the profile.
        var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings("[user@tenant]", authDelegate, "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        engineSettings.Identity = new Identity("[user@tenant]");

        //set custom settings for the engine
        engineSettings.CustomSettings = customSettings;

        var fileEngine = Task.Run(async () => await fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result; // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

        var handler = Task.Run(async () => await fileEngine.CreateFileHandlerAsync(inputFilePath,
                                                                inputFilePath,
                                                                true)).Result;

        handler.RemoveProtection();

        var result = Task.Run(async () => await handler.CommitAsync(outputFilePath)).Result;
        
        // Application Shutdown
        handler = null; // This will be used in later quick starts.
        fileEngine = null;
        fileProfile = null;
        mipContext = null;

    }
}
```

However it throws the following error:

NoPolicyException: Label policy did not contain data, CorrelationId=3268dfdf-2ea3-4958-9c72-fe88ae3c6f59, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile, NoPolicyError.Category=SyncFile, NoPolicyError.Category=SyncFile

at

```
var fileEngine = Task.Run(async () => await fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;
```

Can canyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you haven't configured or published a label policy in Security and Compliance Center (https://security.microsoft.com).

For this use case, you don't necessarily need to publish labels. Add this to your engine settings:

```
engineSettings.ProtectionOnlyEngine = true;
```

That'll skip loading the policy and should allow you to decrypt the MSG files. You won't be able to read or apply labels until you publish the label policy and remove that setting, though.